# Optimizing mongo queries - _id or traverse whole collection

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I'm using mongodb for a project. Need to know which would be a better implementation for queries.

Consider I have to search for 10 documents out of a total 1000 documents based on a condition (not id).

1. Would it be better to query using document _id's (after storing the required id's in another collection beforehand by checking for the condition whenever insertion is done)
   OR
2. Would it better to traverse all the documents and get the required documents using the condition

The main aim here is to split documents into different categories and display the documents belonging to a particular category. So storing id's of documents belonging to each category or search for documents in that category by traversing through all the documents?

I have heard that mongodb uses hashed indexing (so feel option 1 would be faster), but I couldnt find anything regarding that. So a small description regarding document storage and queries would also be good.

Comment: The optimum way to query would depend on the nature of the condition and the content of the document.  Can we see an example?

Comment: Yeah sure,  I have a document containing names of hotels and I want to search for all Chinese restaurants. Would it be better to have sthng like type:"Chinese" or Chinese:"no" inside each document or keep another collection categories and have Chinese:[id1, id2, id3...]

Comment: Just want to know whether searching for each Id using some for loop is better or traversing the whole restaurants collection and fetching each restaurant satisfying the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimum way to query for the cuisine type example would be to store what the restaurant serves in an array of strings or objects, and index that field.

For example:

```
{
  name: "International House"
  cuisine: [
    { name: "Chinese", subtype: "Kowloon"},
    { name: "Japanese", subtype: "Yakitori"},
    { name: "American", subtype: "TexMex" }
  ]
}
```

Then create an index on `{ "cuisine.name": 1 }`.

When you need to find all restaurants that serve Chinese food, the query:

```
db.collection.find({"cuisine.name":"Chinese")
```

will use that index, and only scan the documents that match.

Comment: So,option 2 ryt? Could you also explain why it is preferred over the first one? Would be of great help 

Comment: Not really, this is option 3.  If you create the index on the field containing the data, it won't traverse all of the documents, and won't use the _id index.

Comment: Ohh, I thought it would take linear time, going through all the documents. So how is the storage implemented in mongodb to facilitate such queries? Any ideas?

Comment: The key is to create the additional index, which is essentially a map from specific field values to documents.  When you query, mongodb can scan the index to find the value you are looking for, and then fetch just the documents that contain that value.